# Google Calendar Event -> Invalid date/time format: 0001-12-28T23:40:36-03:06:28

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Hello Google Calendar API team,

We receive an event in Google cal feed using `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Events.List.execute()` that the library `google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc` can't handle. How do you suggest we work around this problem?

```
{
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"2814305416392000\"",
   "id": "...",
   "status": "confirmed",
   ...
   "created": "2014-08-03T21:47:50.000Z",
   "updated": "2014-08-05T01:41:46.086Z",
   "summary": "...",
   ...
   "start": {
   "dateTime": "0001-12-28T23:40:36-03:06:28"   <<<< the issue
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2014-08-23T21:00:00-03:00"


Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time format: 0001-12-28T23:40:36-03:06:28
    at com.google.api.client.util.DateTime.parseRfc3339(DateTime.java:290) ~[google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
    at com.google.api.client.util.Data.parsePrimitiveValue(Data.java:430) ~[google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:841) ~[google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This is clearly a bug. You can try to work around this until it gets fixed by patching the corrupted start time with an update or a patch call. Alternatively you could delete the event.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that your start date is `0001-12-28T23:40:36-03:06:28`

[originalStartTime.dateTime](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events)

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC
>   3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly
>   specified in timeZone.

I would read though [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) but I don't think there is any way that 0001 is a valid year.

If that doesn't fix the problem you could either check the issue log or log it as an issue yourself [Google-Calendar-api issues](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-Calendar)

Comment: We run a synchronization service so I am not sure how those illegal format dates are entered into Google calendar. We simply seem to get them when querying events and the google lib breaks. I'll keep an eye on this. If it continues happening I'll file the bug. Thanks