# Invalid Date display on google calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am creating events on google calendar using PHP. 
Event is created successfully but it displays wrong time on calendar.

```
$start = '2016-08-04T13:30:00.000+02:00';
$end = '2016-08-04T18:00:00.000+02:00'
$timezone= 'Europe/Zurich';

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => $eventname,
            'location' => $address,
            'description' => $description,
            'start' => array(
              'dateTime' => $start,
              'timeZone' => $timezone,
            ),
            'end' => array(
              'dateTime' => $end,
              'timeZone' => $timezone,
            ),
            'attendees' => array(
              array('email' => $contactemail),
            ),
            'reminders' => array(
              'useDefault' => FALSE,
              'overrides' => array(
                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
              ),
            ),
          ));

        $event = $service->events->insert($calid, $event);
```

Using this code the event is created successfully. 
When i check the event on calender it shows wrong time.

See this url for it. http://awesomescreenshot.com/00b62fl6ed

And when i click on edit event then check the
Startdate and enddate is correct with time.

See this url for it. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0df62fkn00

but the issue is that it shown incorrect on calendar.
Please check my code and tell me what is wrong there.

Comment: You check your code and find what is wrong! SO is **not a free Debugging service**

Comment: Well as this code would not compile you are obviously not using this code. So what would be the point of us checking code you are not using for errors in code you are using

Comment: Looks just a timezone issue in your main calendar display. Are you using the same timezone? (Zurich +02)

Comment: @RiggsFolly:- i checked many times. but i did not find any issue.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257753/google-calendar-event-invalid-date-time-format-0001-12-28t234036-030628) and also check the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have the typo in your code. In the second row is missing semicolon at the end.

```
$end = '2016-08-04T18:00:00.000+02:00';
```

However I think, that this error will be in google calendar setup . Try to look to google calendar setup on timezone if is in harmony of your timezone.

Comment: :- still same issue

Comment: In that case it's difficult to advise remotely. Try and check.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Get date in RFC3339
 * For example used in XML/Atom
 *
 * @param integer $timestamp
 * @return string date in RFC3339
 * @author Boris Korobkov
 */
function date3339($timestamp=0) {

    if (!$timestamp) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }
    $date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $timestamp);

    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/^([\-+])(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', date('O', $timestamp), $matches)) {
        $date .= $matches[1].$matches[2].':'.$matches[3];
    } else {
        $date .= 'Z';
    }
    return $date;
}

?>
```

> Background: From
>   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-xpath/ I
>   saw "The published and updated elements use the RFC 3339 time-stamp
>   format. "
>
> And figured I ought google "rfc3339 PHP" to find a function that
>   implements this format

Comment: :- still same issue